# MessageBox not resolving to MessageBoxW?

Tags: winapi, api

Scenario 1
I created an empty vc++ project added a c file to it and the #include. Now in my main() function if I hover my mouse over the MessageBox func., it resolves to MessageBoxA.

Scenario 2
I create a win32 windows project now here MessageBox resolves to MessageBoxW???
I checked the Project properties->c/c++->preprocessor property there I found **WIN32** defined so I did that in my previous project but still the same result.

What should I do.Yeah of course I can use the latter type of project but think of me as one stubborn rookie who wants to learn the tid-bits.

thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The default "Character Set" property for a new empty project is "Multi-Byte", which means that the preprocessor will not define the `UNICODE` preprocessor symbol and so `MessageBox` will be replaced by `MessageBoxA`.

For a Win32 project, the default "Character Set" property is "Unicode", which means the preprocessor *will* define `UNICODE` and thus `MessageBox` will be replaced by `MessageBoxW`.

See the MSDN article [Working with Strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ff381407%28VS.85%29.aspx) for an introduction.

Answer (score 3):

This is determined by the presence or otherwise of the UNICODE conditional which is determined by the project configuration: either Unicode or Multi-byte character set.

Answer (score 1):

Project + Properties, Configuration Properties, General.  It is the Character Set property.  Only create empty projects after you figured out how *everything* works.  Albeit that the quickest way to learn is by making all the mistakes.

Answer (score 1):

General recommendation: always use MessageBoxW(). There's very little reason to compile your program with MBCS setting, which literally means "textually broken".

Comment: It's better to write MessageBox and allow the conditionals to map to MessageBoxW - it reads much nicer this way

Comment: @david Allow me to disagree. Wrong code must be made look wrong as fast as possible.